# Submit a form without Reloading on a JSP

Tags: java, jsp

Is it possible to make JSP page that updates without reloading

I have search this for a little while now and all of them directs to using AJAX or JQuery...

But I need to use JSP is it possible?

Comment: JSP is server side technology. That means you need to send a request, the server needs to process the JSP and return back a response. Use Javascript.

Comment: ok so does that mean I will use JSP to send the request and Javascript processes the request? or Javascript sends the request then JSP process it

Comment: The JSP will contain a `javascript` `<script>` that will send the request asynchronously and modify the HTML tree.

Comment: Your javascript will call another JSP (or servlet) using AJAX. This call will be done in background, so user will not see the page called.

Comment: So it can it go like this? JSP gets my input and stuff I send the data via Javascript to another JSP page to be process And send it back and be read by a JSP like this?

Comment: JSP just writes out html.  That's all it does (basically).  So one JSP writes out the html form and the javascript to the browser.  Then the user fills out the form and clicks a button. Javascript responds to the button click and sends an AJAX request to another JSP, which responds, and the javascript receives the response and does something with it.